# Gradle DSL method not found: 'complie()' with firebase dependency

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Build.gradle (Module.app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pranav.mychat"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    complie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Build.gradle(Project:MyChat)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I add the firebase real time dependency in the build.gradle

> (Module:app) Gradle DSL method not found: 'complie()' error occurs

But when I remove the firebase real time dependency then there is not problem in gradle build

What should I do ?

Comment: Look at this `complie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'` in your first dependencies section. Change it to compile and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is `compile` you have written `complie` in your database dependency.

Comment: Stating where he did it would help him more than repeating the error message, wouldn't it?